# Jquery - Click outside and Hide Div

Tags: jquery, html, click, hide, show

I am using this: http://www.useful-dates.com/search/

How should the script be written to say,
 1. When the user clicks the input, the scrolled div is shown.
 2. When the user click outside of the scrolled div, the scrolled div hides.

Like this, but i have had no luck re-writting the script: http://rob-bell.net/static/ddlist.html

Iv searched and tried all kinds of things on the net and no luck, please help?

Comment: please provide some pieces of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is when your script is triggered to display the list (the scrolled div) it creates a trigger to the click event on the document itself aswell. Something like this:

```
$("selector to your div").click(function() {
    var scrolledDiv = $("selector to your scrolled div");
    scrolledDiv.show();
    $(document).one(function() {
        scrolledDiv.hide();
    });
});
```

By using the `one()` the code to hide the scroll list will only be executed once, so it wont run each time the user is clicking the document. But remember that it will also trigger on clicks inside your scrolling div, if you dont want that stop the propagation of the click event like this:

```
$("selector to your scrolled div").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: <p>
In relation to the example above:
<br />
<br />
http://www.useful-dates.com/search/
<br />
<br />

<br />
<br />
Would the correct script be:
<br /><br />

</p>

Comment: If I add a id here:
<div id="searchResults" style="padding-left: 6px;height:95px;width:285px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;margin: 2px 0 0 0;">

Comment: $("selector to your div").click(function() {
    var scrolledDiv = $("#searchResults");
    scrolledDiv.show();
    $(document).one(function() {
        scrolledDiv.hide();
    });
$("#searchResults").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
});

Comment: I tried this,

please view http://www.useful-dates.com/search/


Still not working

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of your example ;

```
            $(document).click(function(){

                $('.ddcontainer > div > ol').hide();

            });
```

This hides the div when there has been a click on the document.

Give you div an ID like so:

`<div id="searchResults" style="height:95px;width:290px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;margin: 2px 0 0 0;">`

and then:

```
$(document).click(function(){

    $('#searchResults').hide();

});
```

Alternatively and maybe a better solution is to use `focus` and `blur`:

```
$("#kwd_search").focus(function(){
    $('#searchResults').show();
}).blur(function(){
    $('#searchResults').hide();
});
```

This will show the results when the focus is put onto the input, and removes it when you 'leave' the input.

**UPDATE**

With the autocomplete plugin, you can perform a task after the item has been selected like this:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
}).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    location.href = ui.item.value; // If the value of the item is a url, this will forward you to it
});
```

Comment: So if I want to hide the div whenever it is being clicked outside of it, I shoudl use somthing like:
<pre>$(document).click(function(){

                $('#searchresults > div > table').hide();

            });</pre>

??

Comment: Rather use the last solution I have provided. Otherwise the code I have posted will work, dont need to use ` > div > table`

Comment: Cool, just let us know what solution you used and accept the answer for future reference.

Comment: I used:<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#searchResults').hide();
});
$("#kwd_search").focus(function(){
    $('#searchResults').show();
}).blur(function(){
    $('#searchResults').hide();
});
});
</script>

Comment: But now Im faced with the problem that the <a href=''></a> tags are not working? you can see here:www.useful-dates.com

Comment: There is no click event on the links.. Try adding this JS: `$("#my-table a").click(function(){ $("#kwd_search").val($(this).val()); })`

Comment: You should rather look at using the jQuery autocomplete plugin; http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ this will also allow users to navigate through the results with their keyboards.

Comment: I tried it but not displaying properly... I have attahed all the relevant style sheets and scripts but it is displaying incorrectly. see at: www.useful-dates.com

Comment: You need to link to the jQuery UI CSS file as well: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Youv helped me out SOO much mate, much apriciate all this help. I just have one more issue, how can I make the dropdown list have a link to a URL (Input a '<a href=''></a>' tag)?

Comment: I managed to call the value, but all it does is fill the input field with the value, I want the page to be directed to the value URL. www.useful-dates.com

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned above but because I am such a beginner at jquery I am still struggleing. Could you please check www.useful-dates.com

Comment: I see now that I implemented it incorrectly, but now works. Perfect, that is exactly whet I wanted. small thing, is there anyway to remove the value from appearing within the input field?