# jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it, but not on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240869/jquery-click-outside-and-hide-div) and I am  using this code:

```
    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $("YOUR CONTAINER SELECTOR");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

The problem with this code is that if I click on the scrollbar closes the div!

Suggestions?

Comment: Where is your scrollbar / post your HTML code.

Comment: Instead of `$(document).mouseup(function (e){ ` try `$(document).on('mouseup','body',function (e){`

Comment: I mean the scrollbar of the page. With 'body' not function if I click on the part of page where isn't another div

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice because the code above is not enough to spot what causes the error ;)

Comment: maybe, you should try to attach the mouseup event to 'body' ?

Comment: with 'body' not work because I have several div with absolute positioning, otherwise it would be the perfect solution.
I solved by adding a wrapper div width and height 100% under container and attacking it the mouseup event. Thanks to all

Comment: I have noticed this problem too. Having a scrollbar in IE does not work, the div will close because the event.target is the <html> node when trying to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Use mousedown event instead.

```
$(document).mousedown(function (e) {
   //same code here
});
```